# Why am I getting the error: Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE?

Tags: regex, perl, scripting, command-line-arguments

I am having trouble figuring out why am I getting the error defined in the title.

This is the line of code I'm inputting into the command line:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(\/(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)' myfilepath
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is go through a body of text, find all the URLS and append something to the end of the domain. For example:
https://thisisalink.com/navigate/page <-- I want to ignore the ]

I keep getting this error when I run that code though:

> Unmatched [ in regex; marked by <-- HERE in *)|[ <-- HERE A-Z0-9+&@#%=~_|5.030003)/gxi)/ at -e line 1, <> line 1.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: A suggestion: you should build your regex incrementally, rather than trying to get the whole thing right at the first try. For instance, you are trying to match literal parenthesis (`\(`), which seem unlikely to be in an URL. Also, it seems that you wanted to use `/gxi` flags, except that they appear in the middle of the regex instead of at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$]` is a [special variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$%5D) that contains the current version of the Perl interpreter used. Hence, `[A-Z0 9+&@#%=~_|$]` is interpolated as `[A-Z0 9+&@#%=~_|5.032001` (on my Perl 5.32.1), and the opening `[` is thus unmatched. To fix this, escape the `$` using `\$`:

```
[A-Z0 9+&@#%=~_|\$]
```

Similarly, earlier in the regex, you are using `[...$?...]`, except that `$?` is also a [special variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$?) containing *The status returned by the last pipe close, backtick (``) command, successful call to wait() or waitpid(), or from the system() operator*. This does not cause any error since it should be an integer, but it will no match either `$` or `?` as you'd like. Once again, escape the `$` using `\$?`.

In general, when you want to match a literal `$`, you should probably escape it.